# Wha is TSLM equivalent of R in python?

Tags: python, r, time-series, olsmultiplelinearregression

OLS in python does multiple linear regression without considering the timestamp. What is the equivalent of TSLM of R in Python, which takes timestamp into consideration.

Comment: It's just ordinary lm where the time are indices. Tslm is old

Comment: i guess you want this; https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.tsatools.add_trend.html